# yield doesn't work with pandas.DataFrame.itertuples()?

Tags: python, pandas

It seems that `yield` doesn't work with `pandas.DataFrame.itertuples()`, why?

```
 dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)     
 df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))

 def f():
   for r in df.itertuples():
     yield r

 print(f().next())
 print(f().next())
```

The 1st row got outputted twice.

**EDIT**

source code:

```
  DataHandler(object):
     def __init__(self, csv_dir):
        self.csv_dir = csv_dir
        self.data = pd.DataFrame()
        self._open_convert_csv_files()

     def _open_convert_csv_files(self):
        self.data = pd.read_csv(self.csv_dir)

     def _get_new_row(self):
        for t in self.data.itertuples():
           yield t

     def get_N_rows(self, N=1):
          list = []
          for i in range(N):
             row = self._get_new_row().next() # problem is here
             list.append(row)
          return list
```

I am calling `self._get_new_row()` in `get_N_rows`, which is the problem, every time I call `_get_new_row()` I only get the 1st row, how would I make `g = _get_new_row()` for `g` as a member?

Comment: I think I got it, inside `__init__` do `self.g = self._get_new_row()` and changing `self._get_new_row().next()` to `self.g.next()` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `f` twice, and hence `df.itertuples` twice.

You meant

```
g = f()
print(g.next())
print(g.next())
```

By the way `f` is a pretty pointless thing to define. Hopefully this looks quite different from code you're actually planning to use.

Comment: @Allanqunzi, Post your whole files for the class definition and the usage of the class.